# How to compare array before removing its items in SwiftUI?

Tags: ios, arrays, swift, swiftui

How can i compare original items of an array before i remove them? I have an array of items that get removed every time they are showed and get added into the empty array... to avoid index out of range i was trying: `if emptyArray.count < array.count { //append element }` but it is not working as expected because elements of the full array get removed from it in order to be unique, so it works until the empty array contains half the elements of the full one

```
func changeNumber() {
        if appearedNumber.count < numbers.count { // <-- doesn't work because he lost items
            appearedNumber.append(currentNumber)
            
            let index = Int.random(in: 0..<numbers.count)
            currentNumber = numbers[index]
            numbers.remove(at: index) // remove items from full array
        }
    }
```

#### Full code

```
struct ContentView: View {
    @State private var numbers = ["0", "1", "2", "3", "4", "5"]
    @State private var currentNumber = ""
    
    @State private var appearedNumber = [String]()
    
    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            VStack {
                NavigationLink {
                    SecondView(appearedNumber: $appearedNumber)
                } label: {
                    Text("Change view")
                }
                .padding()
                
                Text(currentNumber)
                    .font(.largeTitle)
                    .bold()
                
                Button {
                    changeNumber()
                } label: {
                    Text("Change person")
                        .font(.largeTitle)
                        .bold()
                }
                .padding()
            }
        }
    }
    func changeNumber() {
        if appearedNumber.count < numbers.count {
            appearedNumber.append(currentNumber)
            
            let index = Int.random(in: 0..<numbers.count)
            currentNumber = numbers[index]
            numbers.remove(at: index)
        }
    }
}


struct SecondView: View {
    @Binding var appearedNumber: [String]
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            ForEach(0..<appearedNumber.count, id: \.self) { index in
                Text(appearedNumber[index])
                    .font(.largeTitle)
                    .bold()
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Use `ForEach(appearedNumber, id: \.self) { number in` instead of an index.

Comment: This function should do work if numbers.count > 0. And your append should happen after current assignment. Last element should be appended manually.

Comment: @JoakimDanielson is correct. Also, rather than randomizing each time you draw a number, created it like `@State private var numbers = ["0", "1", "2", "3", "4", "5"].shuffle()`. This creates a randomized array, and you can draw them out one at a time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can simplify this greatly by shuffling the array...

```
@State private var numbers = ["0", "1", "2", "3", "4", "5"].shuffled()
```

then:

```
func changeNumber() {
    if numbers.count > 0 {
        currentNumber = numbers.removeFirst()
        appearedNumber.append(currentNumber)
    } else {
        currentNumber = "out of numbers"
    }
}
```

---

**Edit** - in response to comment...

If you want the first random number displayed when the view appears, add `.onAppear()`:

```
var body: some View {
    NavigationView {
        VStack {
            NavigationLink {
                SecondView(appearedNumber: $appearedNumber)
            } label: {
                Text("Change view")
            }
            .padding()
            
            Text(currentNumber)
                .font(.largeTitle)
                .bold()
            
            Button {
                changeNumber()
            } label: {
                Text("Change person")
                    .font(.largeTitle)
                    .bold()
            }
            .padding()
        }
    }
    // add this
    .onAppear() {
        changeNumber()
    }
}
```

Comment: I know it, but the question is how to compare an empty array that is getting filled with the original value of another one that is getting emptied

Comment: @simonaus -- trying to make sense of what your goal is... in your post you said: *"it works until the empty array contains half the elements of the full one"* ... well, if you change this: `if appearedNumber.count < numbers.count {` to this: `if numbers.count > 0 {` you won't have that problem. Maybe that gives you your desired result?

Comment: This works but nothing will be displayed until the user presses the button for the first time... what if i want to show one of those numbers as soon as the app is launched?

Comment: @simonaus - implement `.onAppear()` ... see the **Edit** to my answer.